# Emacs Wishlist: what features is emacs lacjing right now?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Emacs is great. To me at least, Emacs is a metaphor of all software. Still,  I know that it lacks some features sometimes that you have to actually migrate to other environments. Given emacs is so customizable, and great and everything, we only have to wish for it right? What do you think is a feature that emacs lacks right now?

Note: As of Emacs 23, there is support for `M-x butterfly`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to turn into a "it should do this" - "it already does this and here's how" series of responses. Good question.

Comment: Sure you aware this is stackoverflow, not emacs bug tracker?

Comment: There are similar posts regarding Visual Studio and everybody is happy.

Comment: This seems like an overly contrived "vote-magnet" question.  "it lacks some features sometimes that you have to actually migrate to other environments."  Right, like it doesn't make omelettes.

Comment: Hmm, I will keep this question for a week or so, if hate accumulates way too much I'll remove it, don't worry. :D

Answer (score 11):

There is a [wishlist](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en?CategoryWishList) on [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/).

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. Great link. I think that we can that advantage of the SO voting mechanism to recognize which are those features that the Emacs community should focus on.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to see a better package manager for emacs. Perhaps something like [RIP](http://hellorip.com/)? [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/) looks interesting, but I don't like that it's trying host and consolidate all the packages. I'd prefer to be able to add modules from any git or cvs repository I find. I'd also like the modules in this theoretical package manager to have a standard way to include icons and info file. Finally, I'd like it to have a dead-simple method of compiling all modules.

I've tried to modularize my emacs files in this style (see my [github emacs.d repo](http://github.com/zpinter/emacs.d/tree/master)), though I'd happily ditch it if something better gained widespread support.

Comment: Yes, I also think that the ELPA is quite interesting,  now with the emacs-starter-kit gaining some popularity and all. I think that the Emacs community should work on deciding for a place to share all the elisp code that is not only some link to an out-dated version of the plugin. The Emacs wiki is great sometimes, but you often have to do elisp archaeology in order to obtaing a recent version of a plugin. (e.g. auto-complete.el) I imagine a kind of rubygems/github interaction in here. That would be great.

Comment: zpinter: To add modules from any git, cvs, svn, darcs, bzr repository, Emacs Wiki file, ELPA package, debian apt-get package, or arbitrary URL, you want to use https://github.com/dimitri/el-get. It provides a decent number of named 'recipes', but it's simple to configure your own for any useful code that you find.

Answer (score 6):

An implementation of elisp that's not 1985's state of the art. I mean, seriously -- global variables everywhere? A non-reentrant parser? It's like they don't *want* people to work on it. I briefly looked at adapting Emacs to be a shared library, but I couldn't get past even *parsing* elisp files.

Comment: The variables aren't global, they are dynamic.

Comment: No, global. 
http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/emacs/src/lread.c?root=emacs&view=annotate

See for example, lines 171-174.

Answer (score 5):

I wish a standard code sense autocompletion(hippie-expand is some kind out of date), and a better GUI to support such things as the flowing completion candidates list which should be no worse than that of VIM.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since Emacs is moving to guile, meaning modern lisp is imminent, the only things I want is the ability to add buttons somewhere. A button browser, or a toolbar buffer would be nice.

On the other hand, one of the best things about emacs is that it doesn't populate your screen with just about anything.

However, the ability to for instance, make a JUnit testing buffer in it's own buffer, etc. would be great. Perhaps forcing button buffers being in it's own frame of something (a new type of frame, like GUI-frame or something?)

Oh, and better rendering capabilities, and a flash plugin so we don't have to start a separate program just to browse the web.

Edit: By "imminent" I mean imminent as in geologically imminent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have C-x M-c M-butterfly, you really don't need much else.

[image: XKCD doesn't even need butterflies]